# How to Create Multiple Test Runs in Single Request in ALM using rest API and JSON

Tags: alm, hp-alm

I am able to create a single test in a single request but I want to create multiple tests in a single request, I have tried passing entities and collection but unable to achieve the desired output.

```
{"entities":
 [
  {"Fields":
   [
    {"Name":"estimate-devtime","values":[]},
    {"Name":"vc-checkin-time","values":[{"value":"17:12:44"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-time","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"base-test-id","values":[]},
    {"Name":"storage-path","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"vc-start-audit-action-id","values":[{"value":"3"}]},
    {"Name":"configurations-count","values":[{"value":"1"}]},
    {"Name":"id","values":[{"value":"1"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-comments","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"description","values":[{"value":"\r\n\r\n&gt;test1 desc\r\n\r\n"}]},
    {"Name":"name","values":[{"value":"Test1"}]},
    {"Name":"has-linkage","values":[{"value":"N"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-status","values":[{"value":"Checked_In"}]},
    {"Name":"has-criteria","values":[{"value":"N"}]},
    {"Name":"dev-comments","values":[{"value":"\r\n\r\ntest 1 comment\r\n\r\n"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-version-number","values":[{"value":"2"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-checkin-user-name","values":[{"value":"sa"}]},
    {"Name":"creation-time","values":[{"value":"2012-01-01"}]},
    {"Name":"template","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"last-modified","values":[{"value":"2012-01-01 17:14:31"}]},
    {"Name":"status","values":[{"value":"Design"}]},
    {"Name":"has-dependencies","values":[{"value":"0"}]},
    {"Name":"attachment","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"steps","values":[{"value":"0"}]},
    {"Name":"runtime-data","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"check-out-user-name","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"vc-checkin-date","values":[{"value":"2012-01-01"}]},
    {"Name":"subtype-id","values":[{"value":"MANUAL"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-end-audit-action-id","values":[{"value":"3"}]},
    {"Name":"parent-id","values":[{"value":"1001"}]},
    {"Name":"exec-status","values":[{"value":"Passed"}]},
    {"Name":"test-ver-stamp","values":[{"value":"13"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-checkin-comments","values":[{"value":"t 1 checked in"}]},
    {"Name":"vc-date","values":[]},
    {"Name":"owner","values":[{"value":"sa"}]},
    {"Name":"text-sync","values":[{}]},
    {"Name":"step-param","values":[{"value":"0"}]},
    {"Name":"timeout","values":[]}
   ],
  "Type":"test"
  }
{"Fields":
   [
   ... Repeat for each entity
   ],
   "Type":"test"
   }
 ],
 "TotalResults":1
}
```

But this is not helpful for me. I am getting errors continuously.

the error is

```
qccore.general-error, Nocontent to map to object due to end of input.
```